# How to avoid unwanted content from input received or data passed using Hashmap

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jax-ws

i am creating web service in which web method will receive a data in Soap+xml i had created the Pojo class for it what i had planned is to process it using Hash map.
My input data as object will be :

```
POST http://www.hutiamdps.com/IHutiGprsModem/dataservice.java HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://www.hutiamdps.com/IHutiGprsModem/pudata"
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Content-Length: 1581

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ihut="http://www.hutiamdps.com/IHutiGprsModem">
<soap:Header>
................
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<autoip>1034|Chromepet|Chennai117.97.24.32</autoip>
</soap:Body
</soap:Envelope>
```

---

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "operation")
    public String operation(@WebParam(name = "xmldata") Object xmldata)
    { 
       .........
return ;
     }
```

To avoid that content upto soap envelope and also tags to process it get xml tags values out of it please tell me is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Could you expand your question little bit? How exactly would you like to use Map (HashMap) and where do you see problem with that?

(I don't have enough reputation to comment so have to post this as answer instead of comment)

Comment: thanks for your reply i will tell you briefly what's my plan is to get an soap+xml tags as input then remove tags as < and > symbols and also the words or strings which are unwanted too. thus i am trying to store whole content in hashmap after extracting data which are unwanted. my input : <ihutidata xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" devsrlno="101" signalstrength="30" devicedatetime="01/24/2010 10:10:23 AM">        my output should be like this devsrlno="101" signalstrength="30" devicedatetime="01/24/2010 10:10:23 AM" i think it can be done can you tell me how